# Memory allocation in MSVC++ 2019

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, visual-c++-2019

I have a question regarding the memory allocation, particularly when using MSVC2019.

I have a C++ program compiled to x64.
By debugging I saw, that allocating variables result in very high pointer addresses, pointing into locations over the first 4GB address space (32bit). If I check the program in the Task Manager, I see it is using only around 30-50MBs of memory.

What is the reason that the variables are not allocated in the lower part of the virtual memory space when practically the whole address space under 4GB is unused?

I would expect the allocation to start from low addresses, and until the first 4GB space used, no need to allocate space over this.

Why is this interesting for me:
I have a big SW containing more than 15 years old C++ code, which was not everywhere prepared to be 64bit, on many places it casts pointers to 32bit types and by this the pointers are damaged. Most probably the original authors assumed the pointers are 32bit. What should be practically true also when compiled to 64bit, hence the program is not using much memory, the memory usage does not grow over 4GB. And it seems when compiled using compilers from 2010, this problem does not appear, probably that time the memory allocations resulted addresses in the first 4GB block even if compiled for x64.

My question is:
can this allocation strategy influenced somehow in MSVC++ 2019? Eg. to instruct he compiler/linker/memory manager to prefer allocation in the first 32bit space until no more is needed? Or, to set a size limit for the virtual address space offered by the memory manager, eg. by setting to 2GB I could achieve there will never be any pointer pointing to an allocated block over 4GB. By this, the old code would survive the cast operations assuming a pointer is 32bit.

I already tried to set NO for high memory awareness in the linker option, and checked the heap parameters, but none of them helped.

Thank you!

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: you wont solve the issue by making sure that your program uses memory that can be enumerated with 32bits. Actually, chances are high that the casts were not correct already with 32bits

Comment: Memory addresses are virtual, they're not mapped directly to physical addresses. This is how virtual memory works.

Comment: Also read up on the concepts around "address space layout randomization" for further reasoning why it's a good thing for programs to end up allocating memory from all across the available address space.

Comment: The question was not why is it a good thing, but how to disable this good thing and go back to the old way. Not all good new things are good for everyone in every case, I'm looking if there's a way to opt out, and get the same behavior on MSVC++2019 like it was on MSVC++2010. If there isn't, then our only way is to fix the code, or to switch to 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your program assumes pointers will be 32-bit, you will just have to compile for 32-bit until you get proper declarations in place using ifdef to check what you are compiling for.

Just pick the x86 instead of x64 from the dropdown as a work around until you modernize your legacy code.

There's more you can do with a big address space, and since the os maps these to portions of physical memory anyway, the compiler simply chose to reap the benefits for keeping different portions of the address space apart for different purposes.

There are ways to create custom heaps and to allocate things on a specific address space if that space is available, however to work these into code would likely take just as long and be going backwards compared to properly allocating correct sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of *virtual memory*! In fact to dynamically allocate memory, the standard library kindly asks the kernel to provide it. And only the kernel is reponsable for the virtual addresses given to the program. As each process has its own virtual address translator, multiple processes can be given the same virtual addresses.
As a programmer, you should never worry about that. Use the memory addresses that the kernel has given to you and keep on. If you have to use legacy code assuming that a pointer cannot exceed 32 bits, you should simply not compile it in 64 bits mode but only in 32 bits mode.

Comment: If the kernel is responsible for providing virtual memory addresses, how can be, that when compiling the same code using MSVC++2010, in 64bit mode, the pointers are under 4GB? It was compiled many years ago using this 64bit setup, and we never got an issue report. When we compile now using MSVC++2019, it immediately runs into pointer truncation. That's why was my first assumption, that maybe something changed in the MSVC++ compiler since 2010 what affects how the allocation works, and maybe there's a compiler option telling "do it like you did it until 2010".

Comment: @RobertV: It may be caused by changes in the underlying OS...